# Blue screen error is occurring after for serial communication after introducing multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, error-handling, out-of-memory

I have developed one application in which i am polling the serial port(sending request and getting response) every after 5 sec. everything was working very fine and i tested it thoroughly.

but when i introduced threading i get the blue screen error regarding physical memory or something as attached below in threading i just separated GUI updating task and polling task.

can anyone suggest me what should i do to remove the same, just stuck and not understanding what to do.

This is happening every time i run the application, i am using profic driver serial to usb driver.

MAIN APPLICATION CODE

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
PollingAllMeters();         
 }


 public void PollingAllMeters()
    {
        int isdbError = 0;
        PollingUtility.MeterClass mData = new PollingUtility.MeterClass();



        for (int index = 0; index < m_slaveID.Length; index++)
        {
            try
            {
                mData = poll.MeterOne(m_slaveID[index]);
                Thread processData = new Thread(() => this.updateData(data));
                processData.Start();
            }
            catch { MessageBox.Show("Inside polling box"); 
         }
      }


    private void updateData(MeterValues data)
    {

        mainFormRef.updateData(data);

    }
```

DLL CODE IN WHICH ACTUAL REQUEST AND RESPONSE ARE HAPPENING

```
enter code here
public MeterClass MeterOne(byte meterID)
    {
        MeterClass data1 = new MeterClass();
                 //Voltage
        mb.SendFc3(meterID, startAdd, register, ref value_meter); //modbus call is made here for         sending and receiving response at serial port
        if (mb.modbusStatus == "Read successful")
        { 
             //do some calculation
        }
        else
        {
            // error handling code to create log file

            if (mb.modbusStatus == "Error in read event")
            {
                isPollError = 21;
            }
            else if (mb.modbusStatus == "CRC error")
            {
                isPollError = 22;
            }
            else if (mb.modbusStatus == "Serial port not open")
            {
                isPollError = 23;
            }
        }


        startAdd = 360;
        register = 2;

        value_meter = new byte[register * 2];
        meterData = new byte[register * 2];

        //Max demand
        mb.SendFc3(meterID, startAdd, register, ref value_meter);
        if (mb.modbusStatus == "Read successful")
        {
            //do some calculation

        }
        else
        {
            // error handling code to create log file

            if (mb.modbusStatus == "Error in read event")
            {
                isPollError = 21;
            }
            else if (mb.modbusStatus == "CRC error")
            {
                isPollError = 22;
            }
            else if (mb.modbusStatus == "Serial port not open")
            {
                isPollError = 23;
            }
        }


        startAdd = 496;
        register = 16;

        value_meter = new byte[register * 2];
        meterData = new byte[register * 2];

        mb.SendFc3(meterID, startAdd, register, ref value_meter);
        if (mb.modbusStatus == "Read successful")
        {
          //do some calcualtion

        }
        else
        {
            // error handling code to create log file

            if (mb.modbusStatus == "Error in read event")
            {
                isPollError = 21;
            }
            else if (mb.modbusStatus == "CRC error")
            {
                isPollError = 22;
            }
            else if (mb.modbusStatus == "Serial port not open")
            {
                isPollError = 23;
            }
        }

        data1.date = DateTime.Now;
        data1.Status = isPollError;
        return data1;      // return result to the main program

    }
```

Comment: Check your hardware and device drivers.

Comment: "I got a blue screen" really isn't enough to help you.  Did it just happen once, is it repeatable?  If so, please provide a code sample capable of replicating the problem.

Comment: Bluescreens are almost always due to bad hardware or bad drivers.  If you are using a USB serial port, try a different vendor (one that writes better drivers or makes better hardware). It's unlikely to be due to your code.

Comment: [Kernel debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) kd will at least let you see what's happening at the time the driver fails.  You may not be able to make certain calls to the driver from more than one thread at the same time.  It may help if you describe what your doing in a multithreaded way.

Answer (score 2):

USB and BlueTooth device drivers that emulate a serial port are notoriously unreliable.  It is a cut-throat business that doesn't leave a lot money to pay a good programmer a decent wage, I guess.  The only thing you can do about it if you can't get a driver update is to destroy the thing so it stops making your life miserable. Take it out to the parking lot and run over it with your car a couple of times.

Do take a good look at your code before you spin up the engine.  "Multi-threading" is a red flag, the driver is oblivious to your program using more than one thread.  Avoid a scenario where you can call Read or Write simultaneously from more than one thread.  A driver should always be resilient to that but this doesn't get put to the test very often.  Rejigger the code if necessary so only a single thread ever reads or writes or use the *lock* statement.

Comment: +1 for `Take it out to the parking lot and run over it with your car a couple of times.` Good to see some physical work being suggested.

Comment: It would probably be more efficient to throw it out into traffic that is already on the road.

Comment: That just isn't nearly as effective.  Wanton destruction is an excellent stress-relief technique.

Comment: @Hans Passant please see the updated question..it will be great if you can provide me some inputs..